# Asymmetric information in capital markets: EU ad-hoc announcements/8-K filings in other countries

Tags: equities, information, corporate-actions

In many countries, companies whose securities are traded on a stock exchange are subject to an ad-hoc disclosure requirement. This ad-hoc announcement publication duty refers to the obligation to immediately publish insider information that are potentially price-relevant for the company's securities in order to reduce information asymmetries between corporate insiders (such managers) and investors

For companies in the European Union, these corporate disclosures are called “ad-hoc announcements” and are ruled in the MAR (Market Abuse Regulation). For companies in the US, these corporate disclosures are called “8-K Filings” respectively “6-K Filings” and are ruled in The Securities Exchange Act of 1934.

I am in search now for similar regulations in other countries, i.e. does anyone know how such compulsory corporate disclosures are called and in which law they are codified in other countries?
I am especially interested in the regulations of further G7 countries (i.e. Argentina, Australia, Brazil, India, Indonsesia, Japan, Mexico, Russia, Saudi Arabia, South Africa, South Korea, Turkey, China).
Many thanks.